# consume content from http on site runing under https

Tags: javascript, http, https

I've created an web Api which returns an HTML output. Also Created a Javascript which calls this API and renders the html content returned from API onto a popup.

I've hosted my API on my server which runs on http(without SSL) and my client(Consumer of Javascript) may run on Http or Https.

This arrangement is working fine for all client running on HTTP but it got failed if client runs on HTTPS. I checked browser logs and it throws an error message like:

[image: ERROR MESSAGE IN BROWSER CONSOLE]

Comment: Yeahs that's a bummer. The error message lays it out pretty clear. Do you have a question?

Comment: You can access Https sources over Http connection. But not Http over https. Security first. You need to put you api behind a secure connection.